# Dynamic traffic routing via multiple GRE over IPsec tunnels

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec, strongswan, netplan, dynamic-routing

### Initial data

I am learning networking based things and strongSwan proper configuration.

Using my own wildcard ssl certificate.
All tunnels are successfully lifted and authorized among themselves, respond in any of sides designated in configurations.
Remote devices cconnect successfully to `master` host, but their traffic remains within this `master` host without further forwarding. Authorization of remote users is carried out through radius plugin.

---

### Problem to be solved

Organisation of the VPN network with a common entry point and multiple exit points (dynamic IP)

The following Ubuntu 20.04 dedicated hosts are available:

1. Host A (master) - x.x.110.138
2. Host B (slave1) - x.x.166.115
3. Host C (slave2) - x.x.178.214
4. Host D (slave3) - x.x.140.120

RoadWarrior client (macOS, iPhone, Android, Win10/11) connects to the `master` host.
Next, client traffic is routed randomly (in the near future I would like to implement this moment through load balancing, but first i need to figure out the basic settings) to one of the `slave` hosts. If any of the GRE tunnels to the `slave` host is dead, then exclude it from the general routing system.
When accessing the network through the `slave` host, client is given an IP address from the host to which he was routed.

---

### Dedicated hosts configurations

**Master-host (x.x.110.138)**

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

*/etc/netplan/01-grecfg.yaml*

```
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    tunToSlave1:
      mode: gre
      local: x.x.110.138
      remote: x.x.166.115
      addresses: [10.0.2.1/24]
      mtu: 1442
      ttl: 255
    tunToSlave2:
      mode: gre
      local: x.x.110.138
      remote: x.x.178.214
      addresses: [10.0.3.1/24]
      mtu: 1442
      ttl: 255
    tunToSlave3:
      mode: gre
      local: x.x.110.138
      remote: x.x.140.120
      addresses: [10.0.4.1/24]
      mtu: 1442
      ttl: 255
```

*/etc/ipsec.conf*

```
config setup
    charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2, net 2"
    strictcrlpolicy = yes
conn %default
    reauth = yes
    rekey = yes
    keyingtries = %forever
    keyexchange = ikev2
    dpdaction = restart
    dpddelay = 5s
    mobike = yes
conn tun-slave1
    left = %defaultroute
    right = x.x.166.115
    authby = pubkey
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftauth = pubkey
    rightauth = pubkey
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    rightid = @mydomain.com
    rightrsasigkey = /etc/central/rsa.cert.pem
    leftsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    rightsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    type = transport
    ike = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    esp = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    auto = start
conn tun-slave2
    left = %defaultroute
    right = x.x.178.214
    authby = pubkey
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftauth = pubkey
    rightauth = pubkey
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    rightid = @mydomain.com
    rightrsasigkey = /etc/central/rsa.cert.pem
    leftsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    rightsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    type = transport
    ike = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    esp = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    auto = start
conn tun-slave3
    left = %defaultroute
    right = x.x.140.120
    authby = pubkey
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftauth = pubkey
    rightauth = pubkey
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    rightid = @mydomain.com
    rightrsasigkey = /etc/central/rsa.cert.pem
    leftsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    rightsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    type = transport
    ike = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    esp = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    auto = start
conn remote-mobile
    dpddelay = 30s
    left = %any
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftsubnet = 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
    right = %any
    rightid = %any
    rightauth = eap-radius
    rightsendcert = never
    eap_identity = %identity
    rightsourceip = 10.10.10.0/24
    rightdns = 8.8.8.8
    type = tunnel
    ike=aes128gcm16-sha2_256-prfsha256-ecp256!
    esp=aes128gcm16-sha2_256-ecp256!
    auto = add
    dpdaction = restart
    ikelifetime = 240m
    keylife = 60m
conn remote-pc
    ike=aes256gcm16-aes256gcm12-aes128gcm16-aes128gcm12-sha256-sha1-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes128gcm12-aes128gcm16-aes256gcm12-aes256gcm16-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128-aes256-sha1-sha256-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024,aes128-aes256-sha1-sha256,aes128-sha1,3des-sha1!
    ikelifetime=720m
    keylife=60m
```

**Slave1-host (x.x.166.115)**

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

*/etc/netplan/01-grecfg.yaml*

```
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    tunToMaster:
      mode: gre
      local: x.x.166.115
      remote: x.x.110.138
      addresses: [10.0.2.2/24]
      mtu: 1442
      ttl: 255
```

*/etc/ipsec.conf*

```
config setup
    charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2, net 2"
    strictcrlpolicy = yes
conn %default
    reauth = yes
    rekey = yes
    keyingtries = %forever
    keyexchange = ikev2
    dpdaction = restart
    dpddelay = 5s
    mobike = yes
conn gre-master
    left = %defaultroute
    right = x.x.110.138 <- slave1 local ip
    authby = pubkey
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftauth = pubkey
    rightauth = pubkey
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    rightid = @mydomain.com
    rightrsasigkey = /etc/central/rsa.cert.pem
    leftsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    rightsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    type = transport
    ike = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    esp = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    auto = add
```

**Slave2-host (x.x.178.214)**

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

*/etc/netplan/01-grecfg.yaml*

```
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    tunToMaster:
      mode: gre
      local: x.x.178.214
      remote: x.x.110.138
      addresses: [10.0.3.3/24]
      mtu: 1442
      ttl: 255
```

*/etc/ipsec.conf*

```
config setup
    charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2, net 2"
    strictcrlpolicy = yes
conn %default
    reauth = yes
    rekey = yes
    keyingtries = %forever
    keyexchange = ikev2
    dpdaction = restart
    dpddelay = 5s
    mobike = yes
conn gre-master
    left = %defaultroute
    right = <- slave2 local ip
    authby = pubkey
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftauth = pubkey
    rightauth = pubkey
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    rightid = @mydomain.com
    rightrsasigkey = /etc/central/rsa.cert.pem
    leftsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    rightsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    type = transport
    ike = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    esp = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    auto = add
```

**Slave3-host (x.x.140.120)**

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

*/etc/netplan/01-grecfg.yaml*

```
network:
  version: 2
  tunnels:
    tunToMaster:
      mode: gre
      local: x.x.140.120
      remote: x.x.110.138
      addresses: [10.0.4.4/24]
      mtu: 1442
      ttl: 255
```

*/etc/ipsec.conf*

```
config setup
    charondebug="cfg 2, dmn 2, ike 2, net 2"
    strictcrlpolicy = yes
conn %default
    reauth = yes
    rekey = yes
    keyingtries = %forever
    keyexchange = ikev2
    dpdaction = restart
    dpddelay = 5s
    mobike = yes
conn gre-master
    left = %defaultroute
    right = x.x.110.138 <- slave3 local ip
    authby = pubkey
    leftcert = cert.pem
    leftsendcert = always
    leftauth = pubkey
    rightauth = pubkey
    leftid = @mydomain.com
    rightid = @mydomain.com
    rightrsasigkey = /etc/central/rsa.cert.pem
    leftsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    rightsubnet = %dynamic[gre]
    type = transport
    ike = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    esp = aes256gcm16-sha384-x25519!
    auto = add
```

---

### Questions

1. How to correctly determine interface parameters for dynamic routing?
   In particular, I'm having trouble getting networks/subnets set up
   correctly at the localhost level. I was able to achieve working
   master->slave1 scheme with [this](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/linux-setup-gre-tunnel) guide, but with many hosts, I
   experience difficulties in understanding :(
2. The issue of correct definition of networks/subnets is also opened for
   listed ipsec configurations - how to correctly define
   `leftsubnet/rightsubnet` parameters for each host in this
   interaction scheme or can i leave just `%dynamic` value?
3. Is it redundant to use [quagga](https://www.nongnu.org/quagga/) for dynamic routing in this case?
4. Is interaction scheme of a set of hosts (master-> slaves) to
   previosly described task correctly defined? BTW I tried to raise tunnels from
   slave hosts to the master host, but each subsequent tunnel overrides
   the previous one :\
5. Are there any errors in the parameters of interfaces and general
   ipsec configs?
6. What rules i should set for iptables within each host? I guess, that
   on each of the three slave hosts it is necessary at least to
   designate the nat table rule for masquerading. Not so long ago, I
   raised only 1 server with strongSwan on board and set up the
   following general rules:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT

   iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in --proto esp -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT

   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

   iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360

   iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
   iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
   iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
   ```

I would really appreciate any help, explanations and useful information.

Cheers <3